# Fixed Button in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, button, scrollview

I want to make a view( a button actually) which is inside a scrollview , but when the user scolls down and the button is going up, it moves up only till it reaches the top of the visible screen and then stays there like a fixed header until the user scrolls up again and then it returns to its original position.

I have given the screens for understanding ;

[At Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqmfE.png)

[Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSvIv.png)

Comment: Post your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

Change you parent viewgroup to RelativeLayout and then make a Button and ScrollBar as a direct child of this RelatieveLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achive this by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
------put your code here-----/>

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i try this one but its not work. Are u sure writing these correctly ? Because scrollview has no child